# Как с помощью js получит все содержимое в тегах h1, h2, h3?

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите как я могу получить все содержимое во всех тегах на странице по h1, h2, h3?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var content = [];
document.querySelectorAll("h1,h2,h3").forEach(function(item){
  content.push(item.textContent); 
});
console.log(content.join());
```

```html
<h1>H1 content</h1>
<h2>H2 content</h2>
<h3>H3 content</h3>
<h1>Second H1 content</h1>
```